# Play Framework | No DB type for JDBC type 2003

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, stack-trace, ebean

```
evolutionplugin=enabled
```

When i create new entity or try to migrate old migration to new database i see that error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No DB type for JDBC type 2003
 com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.DbTypeMap.get(DbTypeMap.java:65)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.DdlGenContext.getDbType(DdlGenContext.java:149)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.DdlGenContext.getColumnDefn(DdlGenContext.java:128)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.CreateTableColumnVisitor.visitScalar(CreateTableColumnVisitor.java:155)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.VisitorUtil.visit(VisitorUtil.java:122)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.VisitorUtil.visit(VisitorUtil.java:73)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.VisitorUtil.visitBean(VisitorUtil.java:62)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.VisitorUtil.visit(VisitorUtil.java:36)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.VisitorUtil.visit(VisitorUtil.java:22)
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.DdlGenerator.generateCreateDdl(DdlGenerator.java:144)
```

don't work for postgres 9.1 to 9.5. Play Framework 2.4, scalaVersion  2.10.4, java 7/8

Comment: Please add the code which causes this exception.

Comment: the exception is the evolution of the plugin and the problem can not understand